# What is the different between the Context I get from the Fragment to the one I get from the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, locale, android-context

I would like to change the entire locate app.

context.resource.configuration.locale = Locale("ar")

My app is single activity one.

I pay attention that changing the locate inside the Context which I receive from the Fragment handle the situation in all my Fragments, unlike changing it from the Activity which I receive no result...

My question is if somebody have a clue why is this happen? or how can I change the app locale in the entire app?

I read some posts and non of them was good enough.

Comment: You said that you only have one activity in your app in which you want to change the app , can you please post the code that you re using to change your app language ?

Comment: Are you using getActivty() to get the Activity Context from within the Fragment?

Comment: Hey, I tried many things..